# how to print decimal values in python

Tags: python, decimal, floating-accuracy

```
print("enter start() to start the program")

def start():
    print("This script converts GBP into any currency based on the exchange rate...")
    print(" ") #enters a line
    exchangeRate = int(input("Enter the exchange rate (Eg: 0.80)"))
    print("how much would you like to convert???")                       
    gpb = int(input())
    print(gpb*exchangeRate)
```

If I put the exchange-rate at 0.81 and I enter £1 it always returns 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) instead of [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) with your `input()` call. I.e.,

```
    gpb = float(input())
```

otherwise if the user enters `0.81`, [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) will truncate this to `0` during the conversion.

By using [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float) you'll keep the decimal value supplied as input and your computation should yield the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You specified type as int.....those are whole numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....) when you multiply 1 by 0.81 you get 0.81.....key number for integers is the one before dot,in this case zero.So like previous answer shortly said just change type of variable.